# Determine programmatically if you are in MySites

Tags: development, my-site

My question is the same as the title:

How can I determine programmatically am in MySites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the WebTemplate property of the current SPWeb, if it is SPSMSITEHOST#0, it is a MySite host.

You can use Get-SPWebTemplate powershell command in SharePoint 2010 Management Shell to see list of out of the box web templates.